# find method of java matcher lost its value

Tags: java, regex

I am using a regular expression to get an exact word in my string. I don't know why the `find()` method is losing it's value. In debug mode I can watch that and the value is true but it doesn't go to the `while`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bAccountability", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("      Accountability: Execute");
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("it work!!!!!!!!!");
  }
}
```

Please can anyone tell me what my problem is? Thank you.

Comment: I'll try on my computer and in `while (matcher.find())` return `true`. Would you give some more explanation about your question, please?

Comment: It works here - http://ideone.com/Q9rLxq (if `find` doesn't return true at least once then there *wasn't* a match)

Comment: If it's not entering the while loop, the problem must lie outside of this code fragment.  This same code, cut and paste as-is, will execute properly, and you will get into the while loop once.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `matcher.find();` you must call `matcher.group();` to return the result of the previous match.

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bAccountability", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("      Accountability: Execute");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```